# Javascript delete does not removed the desired property

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodejs to create a game. It happens that this time I am not able to use Delete. It is not working and I have no idea why.

I execute this line:

```
delete Bullet.list[i]
```

And `Bullet.list` is an object with properties and after executing this line, the desired property is not removed.

Here is my code (you can see the above line of code in context here below):

```
var Map = require("./Map.js")
var Player = require("./Player.js");
var Bullet = require("./Bullet.js");
var Fly = require("./Fly.js");
var Settings = require("./Settings.js");

var Simulation = function(SOCKET_LIST){ 

//Update Bullets
for(var i in Bullet.list){
    var bullet = Bullet.list[i];
    bullet.update();

    var shooter = Player.list[bullet.parent];       
    //Bullets collide with flies
    for(var i in Fly.list){
        var fly = Fly.list[i];
        if(!bullet.toRemove && bullet.getDistance(fly) < 15){
            if(shooter){
                shooter.updateCoins(fly.killCoins);
                shooter.updateXp(fly.killXp);
            }
            bullet.toRemove = true;
            fly.toRemove = true;
        }
    }
    //Collide with player
    for(var i in Player.list){
        var player = Player.list[i];
        if(player.death) continue;
        if(!bullet.toRemove && bullet.getDistance(player) < 32 && shooter !== player.id && shooter.team != player.team && !player.immune){
            player.hp -= 1;
            player.hpChanged = true;
            if(player.hp <= 0){
                if(shooter)
                    player.kill(shooter);
                else
                    player.kill();
            }
            bullet.toRemove = true;
        }
    }
    //Collide with map
    if(typeof shooter == "undefined" || shooter.shootsCollideMap && Map.isColliding(bullet))
        bullet.toRemove = true;

    //Remove bullets
    if(bullet.toRemove){
        delete Bullet.list[i]; /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM. THE PROPERTY IS NOT BEING DELETED*/
        Bullet.removePack.push[bullet.id];
    }

}
```

I am not able to delete the property "i" from the object Bullet.list.

Comment: You should read this: [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).  Is `Bullet.list` an array or an object?  The main purpose of `delete` in Javascript is to remove a property of an object (not to remove an element from an array).

Comment: @jfriend00 Bullet.list is an object where the keys are the the bullet.id. I can access a bullet like this: var Bullet = Bullet.list[bullet.id]. bullet.id is a random number not an array index.

Comment: @vol7ron If I am trying to use delete it is because Bullet.list is an object. I did not mention because I though it was obvious... I am also using for(var i in Bullet.list) so...

Comment: I don't know why people closed this.  It's a simple programming mistake and that mistake is obvious to someone who studies the code.  It's not off-topic at all.  The verifiable example is in the code.  Please vote to reopen.  See my answer if you didn't see the programming issue.

Comment: @DanielOliveira, what do you think `i` holds after you've used it for three loop iterators

Comment: Please vote to reopen.  There's nothing off-topic about this question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - Why did you vote to close this?  It should not have been closed.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Why did you vote to close this?  It should not have been closed.

Comment: @jfriend00 The problem statement is "It is not working and I have no idea why ... I am not able to delete the property "i" from the object Bullet.list." and a code dump. This is not specific enough. It's great that you were able to debug OP's code for him, but that won't help anyone else in the future.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - You said it yourself, the OP is trying to delete an item and it isn't deleting and there's a comment in the code showing the problem line of code.  That is clear if you read the question.  Yes, they could have chosen better words, but a careful reader is not left wondering what was asked here.  Believe me, I vote to close lots of  bad questions, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @jfriend00 Blorgbeard is right. The specific close reason is : ""Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."  "JavaScript Delete not working" is not a useful problem statement. "I don't know why" is not a useful problem statement.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - What is being served here by closing a question that others understand?  The last line of the question is `I am not able to delete the property "i" from the object Bullet.list.`.  And, when you go look in the code for the `delete`, you see this line `delete Bullet.list[i]; /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM. THE PROPERTY IS NOT BEING DELETED*/`.  The info is there.  Not as clear as we'd like, but the info is there to a careful reader.  There's no reason to close a question that was fully understood by a careful reader.

Comment: I am happy with the clarity of the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three `for` loops are all sharing the same variable `i` and thus you aren't deleting the `i` index you want to.  This is because `var i` is function scoped, not scoped to the individual `for` loop.

When you do this:

```
delete Bullet.list[i];
```

The value of `i` is whatever `i` is after your previous `for` loop and probably not the item you actually want to delete.  Perhaps you mean to break out of the `for` loop previously so that `i` will be a specific item you want to remove?

Or you need to separately save to another variable an index of an item that you want to remove.  Or, just remove an item inside the `for` loop when the value of `i` is current.

Remember that `var` is function scoped.  So both your `var i` declarations in your two nested `for` loops are actually referencing the exact same variable, not declaring a new one.  I would recommend changing the name of the loop index in one of the two loops to be a separate variable.

If you are running in an environment where `let` is fully supported, you could use `let i` instead of `var i` and then the value of `i` would be uniquely scoped to only the `for` loop in which it was declared.

Comment: Are you sure? When I wrote this code I was thinking that "i" was a reference  to the var "i" in the outter for loop.

Comment: @DanielOliveira - Nope.  `var` is function scoped.  So both `var i` declarations actually refer to the same variable.  If you used `let` instead of `var`, then what you were thinking would be the case might work.  But, in my book, you should not be using the same variable for nested loops.

Comment: This is the right answer.  The problem is a result of variable scoping.

Answer (score -1):

When you delete an array element, the array length is not affected. This holds even if you delete the last element of the array.

You could try `Bullet.list.splice(i, 1)` as an alternative to `delete`.

There is a lot going on in this code,, hope this helps!

Comment: Bullet.list is not an array. It is an object where the keys are the id of each bullet.

Comment: Sorry! I thought it was an array given the name `list`.  Tried to answer the question without all of the context.